# Postgres query hung when I ran a simple select query

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql

I'm using pandas `read_sql()` method to read tables from my PostgreSQL database. The query is as simple as `SELECT * FROM my_table`. Yesterday, one of those queries failed, and I had to restart the Jupyter notebook after two or three minutes. Initially, I believed the issue was specific to the Jupyter or Pandas library. However, the problem persisted when I attempted the query within a Python file as well. Also, running the query directly in the database manager (DBeaver) did not help.

I'm not going to try to find the cause of this problem because I know there are many things that might contribute to it happening. My main goal is to find a way to stop the query if it exceeds the time limit and eliminate any risk of application crashes. Right now, I'm calling `read_sql()` from inside a try/except block, but since the problem is with the database engine, that obviously doesn't help. I can run the query inside a thread and stop the thread if it takes longer than specified time. Below is a sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import threading
import time

def read_sql_with_timeout(query, engine, timeout=10):
    def read_sql_thread():
        data = pd.read_sql(query, engine)
        return data

    thread = threading.Thread(target=read_sql_thread)
    thread.start()
    thread.join(timeout=timeout)

    if thread.is_alive():
        thread.kill()
        raise TimeoutError("pd.read_sql() call timed out")

    return thread.result()

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://localhost:5432/my_database')
data = read_sql_with_timeout('SELECT * FROM my_table', engine, timeout=10)
```

Since I do a lot of queries in my code, I think the above code is not a good performing code. Another way is to use `asyncpg`, which is a PostgreSQL asynchronous library. The sample code is as follows:

```
import asyncpg
import pandas as pd

pool = await asyncpg.create_pool('postgresql://localhost:5432/my_database')
data = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM my_table', pool)

# OR

connection = await asyncpg.connect('postgresql://localhost:5432/my_database')
data = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM my_table', connection)
await connection.close()
```

My question is, is there any guarantee that I will be able to handle any situation using that library? Also, I would like to know if there is a better way to avoid similar problems?

Comment: Reading the docs  [Statement behavior](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CLIENT-STATEMENT) would be a good start.

Comment: You might like to have a look here [Is there any way to put timeout in pandas read_sql function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56473948/is-there-any-way-to-put-timeout-in-pandas-read-sql-function)

Comment: Thanks @JenilDave Two of the three answers to that question are based on threading, which I don't prefer as I mentioned in my question. However, it's a good idea to use connection arguments when creating the engine and seems to work. BTW, I think I'll have to use `asyncpg` in the future, so I wonder if the asynchronous nature of it guarantees no-freezing queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to limit the length of a running query in PostgreSQL is to use:

```
set statement_timeout='2min';
```

when connecting.

You can then override the timeout for a single transaction if needed:

```
begin;
set local statement_timeout='10min';
select some_long_running_query();
commit;
```

You can also set the default timeout for the whole database server (in a configuration), for a single database (with `alter database`) or a single user or group of users (with `alter role`).

While your query is stuck you should check `pg_stat_activity` view for a cause - specifically `state`, `wait_event` and `wait_event_type` columns should give you a hint.

Comment: Thanks @Tometzky, due to the nature of my code, I need to use "asyncpg". Do you think it's enough to ensure I don't have similar problems, or should I apply your workaround too?

Comment: I don't think that whether you use "asyncpg" or not is relevant. You have to make sure that a query has a timeout on the database side. It is not a work-around too - this is basically a requirement for any reliable client program.